# Docker exposed ports are not available

Tags: docker

I have run a docker container and **docker ports are exposed successfully**. I am trying to access docker container view in the browser but always find web page is not available internally and externally.

here is the ports successfully exposure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKAFw.jpg

and page is not available
[http://imgur.com/a/PYJz5](https://imgur.com/a/PYJz5)

Comment: It sounds that is something firewall related

Comment: Are you certain that the web server is actually listening on that port inside the container? If you attach to the running container, are you able to curl the port and get a response from the web server?

Comment: @Robert, I have turned off the firewall but the same issue exists

Comment: Run this inside your container: `ss -ltnp|cat`. You should see that port listening in all interfaces(`*`, not only localhost.

Comment: @Robert i think that port is not listening http://imgur.com/a/LesTc , i do not know what cause that.

Comment: There is the problem. The application must listen in all interfaces (0.0.0.0), not only localhost., in order to let docker match the internal container IP to the exposed port in the host.

Comment: @Robert - app is already listening to all interfaces http://imgur.com/a/evFC9

Comment: Ramy, that is a misunderstanding. That is `docker ps` showing that he is mapping a port in 0.0.0.0 of your *host* to a port where the container should be listening in all of its interfaces (not only 127.0.0.1 as you showed with `ss` command). Please, try to check if your app is listening to 0.0.0.0. What is your app?